# Sort ListView when clicking header

Tags: .net, windows, listview, c++-cli, clr

I need to sort the content on a ListView based on the click of the ListView header. I´m using C++/CLI, so I got the  [this Microsoft article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/319401/how-to-sort-a-listview-control-by-a-column-in-visual-c) and coded it using C++/CLI.

Here is my result:

**ListViewColumnSorter.h**

```
/// <summary>
/// This class is an implementation of the 'IComparer' interface.
/// </summary>
#pragma once

public ref class ListViewColumnSorter : System::Collections::IComparer
{
    public:

        ListViewColumnSorter();
        virtual int Compare(System::Object^ x, System::Object^ y);

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Specifies the column to be sorted
        /// </summary>
        int ColumnToSort;

        /// <summary>
        /// Specifies the order in which to sort (i.e. 'Ascending').
        /// </summary>
        System::Windows::Forms::SortOrder OrderOfSort;

        /// <summary>
        /// Case insensitive comparer object
        /// </summary>
        System::Collections::CaseInsensitiveComparer^ ObjectCompare;

        property int SortColumn;
        property System::Windows::Forms::SortOrder SortOrder;
};
```

**ListViewColumnSorter.cpp**

```
/// <summary>
/// This class is an implementation of the 'IComparer' interface.
/// </summary>

#include "ListViewColumnSorter.h"

ListViewColumnSorter::ListViewColumnSorter()
{
    // Initialize the column to '0'
    ColumnToSort = 0;

    // Initialize the sort order to 'none'
    OrderOfSort = System::Windows::Forms::SortOrder::None;

    // Initialize the CaseInsensitiveComparer object
    ObjectCompare = gcnew System::Collections::CaseInsensitiveComparer();
}

/// <summary>
/// This method is inherited from the IComparer interface.  It compares the two objects passed using a case insensitive comparison.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="x">First object to be compared</param>
/// <param name="y">Second object to be compared</param>
/// <returns>The result of the comparison. "0" if equal, negative if 'x' is less than 'y' and positive if 'x' is greater than 'y'</returns>
int ListViewColumnSorter::Compare(System::Object^ x, System::Object^ y)
{
    int compareResult;
    System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem^ listviewX, listviewY;

    // Cast the objects to be compared to ListViewItem objects
    listviewX = (System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem^) x; <--- ERROR HERE
    listviewY = (System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem^) y; <--- ERROR HERE

    // Compare the two items
    compareResult = ObjectCompare->Compare(listviewX->SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text,
                                           listviewY->SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text);

    // Calculate correct return value based on object comparison
    if (OrderOfSort == System::Windows::Forms:: SortOrder::Ascending)
    {
        // Ascending sort is selected, return normal result of compare operation
        return compareResult;
    }
    else if (OrderOfSort == System::Windows::Forms::SortOrder::Descending)
    {
        // Descending sort is selected, return negative result of compare operation
        return (-compareResult);
    }
    else
    {
        // Return '0' to indicate they are equal
        return 0;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the number of the column to which to apply the sorting operation (Defaults to '0').
/// </summary>
void ListViewColumnSorter::SortColumn::set(int value)
{
    ColumnToSort = value;
}

int ListViewColumnSorter::SortColumn::get()
{
    return ColumnToSort;
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the order of sorting to apply (for example, 'Ascending' or 'Descending').
/// </summary>
void ListViewColumnSorter::SortOrder::set(System::Windows::Forms::SortOrder value)
{
    OrderOfSort = value;
}

System::Windows::Forms::SortOrder ListViewColumnSorter::SortOrder::get()
{
    return OrderOfSort;
}
```

I´m having a problem compiling this code, on function Compare, where I cannot convert a ListViewItem^ to listviewX and listviewY to get its string (check code marker):

***Expression must have class type***

Advice needed to solve that problem.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1bh3t52k.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the proper way to cast from `Object^` to `ListViewItem^`?

The usual way to cast to a managed type is with `dynamic_cast` or `static_cast`.

I would use `dynamic_cast<ListViewItem^>(x)`, but that does require that you check for `nullptr`. You could also use `static_cast<ListViewItem^>(x)`, which will throw an exception if it's not of the proper type.

Also, note that there's nothing stopping you from implementing the `ListViewColumnSorter` class in C#, and referencing that from C++/CLI.

Comment: Thanks for the cast hint. I´m now facing another problem: `listviewY = static_cast<System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem^>(y);`. Error message = `No operator = matches these operands. System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem = System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem^ `. Where is the `ListViewItem` comes from as they are all `ListViewItem^`? Confused now...

Comment: Found problem. Cannot declare two variables in same line, as: `System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem^ listviewX, listviewY;`. Added 2 statements and all fine now. Thanks for helping @David Yaw

Comment: @Mendes: You can, but only the base type applies to both, you had one variable of type `ListViewItem^` and one `ListViewItem`.  If you want two `ListViewItem^`, repeat the modifiers, that's `ListViewItem ^x, ^y;`