# Expression must have a class type - C++/CLI

Tags: .net, windows, c++-cli

So I have this code which I got inspired from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/319401/how-to-sort-a-listview-control-by-a-column-in-visual-c), someone already had this type of error but this didn't fix it in my case ([article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272838/sort-listview-when-clicking-header)):

```cpp
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
int ListViewColumnSorter::Compare(System::Object^ x, System::Object^ y)
{
    int compareResult;
    ListViewItem^ listviewX;
    ListViewItem^ listviewY;

    // Cast the objects to be compared to ListViewItem objects
    listviewX = static_cast<ListViewItem^>(x);
    listviewY = static_cast<ListViewItem^>(y);

        // Compare the two items
    compareResult = ObjectCompare->Compare(listviewX->SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text,
        listviewY->SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text);

    // Calculate correct return value based on object comparison
    if (OrderOfSort == System::Windows::Forms::SortOrder::Ascending)
    {
        // Ascending sort is selected, return normal result of compare operation
        return compareResult;
    }
    else if (OrderOfSort == System::Windows::Forms::SortOrder::Descending)
    {
        // Descending sort is selected, return negative result of compare operation
        return (-compareResult);
    }
    else
    {
        // Return '0' to indicate they are equal
        return 0;
    }
}
```

However it gives me an error at this line:

```cpp
compareResult = ObjectCompare->Compare(listviewX->SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text,
        listviewY->SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text);
```

telling me that `listviewX` and `listviewY` must have a class type.

I don't understand, as I'm correctly pointing to an object of type `ListViewItem`.

Any ideas?

Comment: `c++` is to `c++-cli`, as `java` is to `javascript`.  Both `c++-cli` and `javascript` are poorly named, because many people think they're some sort of `c++` or `java` (respectively).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is a bit misleading, in a way, because it implies that the problem is with the actual `listviewX` and `listviewY` variables (which, as you have pointed out, *are* 'hatted' class types, or handles).

However, the `SubItems` member of the `ListViewItem` class is an array of **class handles** (not raw classes), so you need the `->` operator on the two occurrences of that, too (rather than the `.` operator).

This is what you need the code to be:

```cpp
compareResult = ObjectCompare->Compare(listviewX->SubItems[ColumnToSort]->Text,
        listviewY->SubItems[ColumnToSort]->Text);
```